# Convert a date and time format to string

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

Inside the `$row['created']`, the date format is like this: **(2017-02-04 03:52:04)**. How could I make it as string or should be like this **(February 04, 2017 - 03:52:04)** in the output? Please help. Thank you!

```
function getEvents($date = ''){
    include 'dbConfig.php';
    $eventListHTML = '';
    $date = $date?$date:date("Y-m-d");
    $result = $db->query("SELECT title,created FROM events WHERE date = '".$date."' AND status = 1");
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $eventListHTML = '<h2>Events On '.date("l, d M Y",strtotime($date)).'</h2>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<ul>';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $eventListHTML .= '<li>'.$row['title'].' - '.$row['created'].'</li>';
        }
        $eventListHTML .= '</ul>';
    }
    echo $eventListHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead,

```
$eventListHTML = '<h2>Events On '.date("F d,Y H:i:s",strtotime($date)).'</h2>';
$eventListHTML .= '<ul>';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $eventListHTML .= '<li>'.$row['title'].' - '.date("F d,Y H:i:s",strtotime($row['created'])).'</li>';
    }
    $eventListHTML .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT title,DATE_FORMAT(created,'%M-%d,%Y - %K:%i:%s') created FROM events
```

DATE_FORMAT() function provided by Mysql can be used to convert Date to string in any format as shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
<?php
$date=date_create("2017-02-04 03:52:04");
echo date_format($date,"F d,Y - H:i:s");
?>
```

According to your code,

```
<?php
    $date=$row['created'];
    echo date_format($date,"F d,Y - H:i:s");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
(new \DateTime('2017-02-04 03:52:04'))->format('r');
```